# dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: No protocol specified

Tags: arch-linux, x11, d-bus

After a recent upgrade in my Arch Linux x64 system, I keep getting this warning message after installing or removing packages with `pacman`.

```
(gconftool-2:5207): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
/usr/bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: No protocol specified
Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.
```

So, far I have not seen any ill effects from this (that I know of), but I would like to make this warning go away.

**EDIT**

I can consistently reproduce this by installing or uninstalling GNOME Do. Both of the following commands result in the output above.

```
$ sudo pacman -S gnome-do
$ sudo pacman -Rns gnome-do
```

Running `xhost +` seems to temporarily alleviate the warning (at least until I reboot). I can run `xhost -` and the warning returns.

**UPDATE**
This problem went away after a few upgrades (i.e. `pacman -Syu`).

Comment: Are you using XFCE? I found this thread: http://code.google.com/p/acpi-eeepc-generic/issues/detail?id=47

Comment: @sim, before doing the update (`pacman -Syu`), I only had GNOME installed. I immediately began seeing the warning after the update. Sometime after the warning started appearing I did install XFCE, KDE, and Cinnamon as well. I am playing around with different desktop environments trying to decide which one I want to use (since I'm ever increasingly disliking GNOME 3). Where it not for that I probably wouldn't have noticed it anymore. The thread you posted though doesn't seem to help. I am only seeing this when using `pacman`.

Comment: As far as I understand what's going on, it's your display manager init script (such as xdm or gdm3) is trying to start X, creates a per-user instance of D-Bus and for some reason GConf fails to connect to its socket.

A common reason for such a problem might be just in that your per-user instance of D-bus is started with wrong permissions, it must run under your UID (see http://askubuntu.com/questions/135573/gconf-error-no-d-bus-daemon-running-how-to-reinstall-or-fix and https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=151914). Try `ps -axfl` and look into UIDs and arguments of your processes.

Answer (score 12):

Try:

```
export $(dbus-launch)
```

and then try any dbus based commands.

Comment: could you explain what that command is doing ? It helped me fix my error but I would like to understand what happened. Edit: I think it logs the user in as you would normally via the desktop environment, but in my case I was only logged in via ssh. so dbus-launch is probably launching that session, right? http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-launch.1.html

Comment: It initializes the dbus-daemon. Ideally that command is executed within a user's login script. More details [here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/dbus.html)

Comment: worked for me on ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Had to install dbus-x11 and run the command above

Comment: In my case this helped - however indirectly since I got an error that I need to run 'apt install dbus-x11' which I did and then everything worked as expected.